# Prototypes in Javascript to Typescript Syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

Does somebody know how do I write this Javascript code into Typescript? Especially the **prototype** inside of the class causes me problems...

```
var Module = (function () {
    function Module(name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    Module.prototype.toString = function () {
       return this.name;
    };
    return Module;
})();

var Student = (function () {
    function Student(name, studentNumber) {
         this.bookedModules = [];
         this.name = name;
         this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
}
Student.prototype.bookModule = function (bookedModule) {
      this.bookedModules.push(bookedModule);
};
Student.prototype.bookedModuleNames = function () {
      return this.bookedModules.map(function (module) {
            return module.toString();
      });
    };
    return Student;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

In typescript you use classes, the compiler will do the prototype work for you.
You code is equivalent to:

```
class Module {
    public name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    toString(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Student {
    public name: string;
    public studentNumber: number;
    public bookedModules: Module[];

    constructor(name: string, studentNumber: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bookedModules = [];
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    bookModule(book: Module): void {
        this.bookedModules.push(book);
    }

    bookedModuleNames(): string[] {
        return this.bookedModules.map(book => book.name);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Module%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Student%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20studentNumber%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20bookedModules%3A%20Module%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20studentNumber%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bookedModules%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.studentNumber%20%3D%20studentNumber%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20bookModule(book%3A%20Module)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bookedModules.push(book)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20bookedModuleNames()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.bookedModules.map(book%20%3D%3E%20book.name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Which compiles into:

```
var Module = (function () {
    function Module(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Module.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    return Module;
}());
var Student = (function () {
    function Student(name, studentNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bookedModules = [];
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
    Student.prototype.bookModule = function (book) {
        this.bookedModules.push(book);
    };
    Student.prototype.bookedModuleNames = function () {
        return this.bookedModules.map(function (book) { return book.name; });
    };
    return Student;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes - typescript will generate this code for you:

```
class Module {
    constructor(public name) {
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Student {
    bookedModules: Module[];   

    constructor(public name, public studentNumber) {
        this.bookedModules = [];
    }

    bookModule(bookedModule: Module) {
        this.bookedModules.push(bookedModule);
    } 

    //...
}
```